# How do I create a REST web service to process Docusign Connect service in C#?

Tags: c#, rest, docusignapi

I want to use the Docusign Connect service, as described in https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/connect-guide.pdf.

I created a REST service using Windows Communication Foundation to accept POST messages from the service. The code in the interface class for two different methods is:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "ProcessConnectMessageStream")]
    string ProcessConnectMessageStream(Stream XMLMessage);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "ProcessConnectMessageRequest")]
    void ProcessConnectMessageRequest(HttpRequestMessage request);
```

The code for the methods is:

```
    public string ProcessConnectMessageStream(Stream XMLMessage)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(XMLMessage);
        string xmlMessage = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Manager mgr = new Manager();
        return mgr.ProcessConnectMessage(xmlMessage);
    }
```

and

```
public void ProcessConnectMessageRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
        try
        {
            // almost all code from https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-csharp
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.GetBaseException().Message;
        }
}
```

I set up a test project that calls the first method. I saved the XML at the end of the Connect Guide (the XML under Sample Connect Message). My test method gets the file and POSTs it. The final method, mgr.ProcessConnectMessage(xmlMessage), is something I wrote to parse the XML. My test works fine. I also created a GET method to make sure the service is functioning. The GET works fine (I am using ngrok to test, so I can call my REST methods over the internet by mapping localhost:port of my project).

As noted in the comment in the 2nd method, I based my code for the 2nd method on what I found on Github to create a method that Docusign Connect should work with.

I've configured Connect on my Docusign test account to work with the methods. I've created envelopes and opened them. Connect will call my methods, as shown in the output from NGROK.

But when either method is called, I get a 400 Bad Request error.

I don't know what else I'm supposed to do to get Connect to communicate with my methods.

Comment: I've used Fiddler (from Telerik) to try to look at the request from Docusign. I don't seem to be able to get the request, but I see a response from my service. The response includes XML that looks just like what's described in the Docusign documentation for the Connect service.

Comment: You are receiving 400 error, which means your Webserver is receiving the Connect Message but somehow your App/Webserver is not able to connect to correct controller/handler. Check the signature of the controller method, if accept type, response types are correct and if there is any required field which is not coming from the DocuSign.

Comment: For some unknown reason, I do not get the 400 error when I created the REST service as a Web API project in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

See my final comment. So, I need at least 30 characters to post this.